# list the number of rows in dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
   df= slNo name
         1   a
         2   b
         3   c
```

I want to add a new column as follows

```
        slNo name  dummy
         1   a      1 
         2   b      2
         3   c      3
```

The code should involve the number of rows in the datafarme and the dummy should be from1 to the no of rows in the dataframe. In R the following is the operation.

```
        df['newcolumn']=c(1:nrow(df))
```

I request someone to guide me. Am unable to find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just assign a numpy array using [np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
In[4]:
df['dummy'] = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
df

Out[4]: 
   slNo name  dummy
0     1    a      1
1     2    b      2
2     3    c      3
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

it will create a new column with the index, which is usually just an incrementing integer

if you want it to start at one you would follow this up with

```
df['index']+=1
```

Comment: So it does not necessarily need a for loop and the length function.

Comment: no, generally speaking, if youre looping a dataframe youre doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not using numpy

```
df['dummy'] = pandas.Series(range(1,len(df) + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple range() function will do**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'slno':[1,2,3], 'name': ['a','b','c']})
df['sd']= list(range(1,len(df['name'])+1))
print df

  name  slno  sd
0    a     1   1
1    b     2   2
2    c     3   3
```

Guess this what you have tried!!